# Cannot execute my application even though the compilation was successful

Tags: java, swing, entry-point

Even though the compilation of the `class` underneath was successful, I cannot get my code to run. The `GUI` is just not showing up. In short, I just want a user to enter an arbitrary `int` into a `javax.swing.JTextField`, and then show an *"italian"* representation of it back to the user. Here's the entire code of my application.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class Example extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public ItalianStringNumberConversionFrame() {
        Container c = getContentPane();
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Convert");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField("Enter Integer: ");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        JLabel label1, label2;
        label1 = new JLabel("Enter an Integer to convert to Italian String:" );
        label2 = new JLabel("The text version of the number entered in Italian is: ");
        panel.add(label1,label2);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(textField);
        c.add(panel);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new Example();
    }
}
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: This cannot be done in a short time, and requires using an external library. Anche perchè l'italiano è più complesso dell'inglese.

Comment: If this is your entire code, how do you run it? Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: And is your question how to convert the integers to text or how to fix the problem with the GUI not being displayed?